# how to add -webkit-line-clamp on this javascript text on css?

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

i hava random-posts script for blogger

```
<div class="noop-random-posts"><script type="text/javascript">
var randarray = new Array();
var l=0;
var flag;
var numofpost=10;
function nooprandomposts(json){
var total = parseInt(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10);
for(i=0;i < numofpost;){flag=0;randarray.length=numofpost;l=Math.floor(Math.random()*total);for(j in randarray){if(l==randarray[j]){ flag=1;}}
if(flag==0&&l!=0){randarray[i++]=l;}}document.write('<ul>');
for(n in randarray){ var p=randarray[n];var entry=json.feed.entry[p-1];
for(k=0; k < entry.link.length; k++){if(entry.link[k].rel=='alternate'){var item = "<li>" + "<a href=" + entry.link[k].href + ">" + entry.title.$t + "</a> </li>";
document.write(item);}}
}document.write('</ul>');}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/mqdefault?alt=json-in-script&start-index=1&max-results=1000&callback=nooprandomposts"></script></div>
```

i would like to add

> "-webkit-line-clamp:3;"

for that javascript in css but how?
what values of it or syntax i should put in CSS

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Javascript Like this

```
document.getElementById("YourId").style.cssText = "-webkit-line-clamp: 3;";
```

Hope it's Help You

Thanks